# solving an ordinary diffrerential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential question:

$$y^{4}(x)(y-x \frac{dy}{dx})((b^{2}-x^2)\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}- x\frac{dy}{dx}+y(x))=c $$

$b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ , $c>0$ are constant numbers and $y=y(x)$.

Thank you for all kind of help and hints.

Comment: Look at each factor. The first and second look very simple. What about the third ?

Comment: what does $y^4$ mean? a derivative?

Comment: $y^{4}=y^{4}(x)$

Comment: Where did this equation come from?